# Как добавлять новую запись в бд, считанную из введенной переменной SQLite3

Tags: c++, sqlite3, insert

```
static int insertData(const char* s)
{
    sqlite3* DB;
    char* messageError;

    string InpLogin;
    string InpPassword;

    cout << "Login: ";
    cin >> InpLogin;
    cout << "Password: ";
    cin >> InpPassword;

    string sql("INSERT INTO Users (Login, Password) VALUES('Admin', '123qwer');"); 
    // Как в значения подставлять переменные InpLogin и InpPassword

    int exit = sqlite3_open(s, &DB);
    /* An open database, SQL to be evaluated, Callback function, 1st argument to callback, Error msg written here */
    exit = sqlite3_exec(DB, sql.c_str(), NULL, 0, &messageError);
    if (exit != SQLITE_OK) {
        cerr << "Error in insertData function." << endl;
        sqlite3_free(messageError);
    }
    else
        cout << "Records inserted Successfully!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как в значения подставлять переменные InpLogin и InpPassword?

Comment: Ну например (один из вариантов) - `string sql = "INSERT INTO Users (Login, Password) VALUES('" +  InpLogin + "', '" + InpPassword + "');";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наиболее правильный способ подставить переменные в запрос — это использовать подготовленные выражение. Одним из преимуществ данного способа является защита от sql-инъекций.

В строке `sql` мы создаём запрос, где в месте, куда мы желаем подставить переменные, поставлены выражения формата `?NNN`. Здесь `NNN` индекс связываемой переменной, начинающийся с единицы. В данном случае это будет `?1` и `?2`.

С помощью метода `sqlite3_prepare_v2` мы создаём экземпляр данного выражения, которое будет хранится в `sqlite3_stmt`.

Далее, с помощью метода `sqlite3_bind_text` мы подставляем в запрос значения связанных переменных. В нём указывается экземпляр выражения `sqlite3_stmt*`, индекс связываемой переменной, значение переменной (в нашем случае текст). Последним аргументом идёт индикатор времени жизни подаваемого на вход объекта. В случае, если гарантируется, что объект будет существовать до завершения работы с выражением, используется `SQLITE_STATIC`, в противном случае `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` заставит метод `sqlite3_bind_text` скопировать выражение для дальнейшего использования.

Выражение со всеми подготовленными переменными выполняется при помощи `sqlite3_step`.

Перед повторным использованием подготовленного выражения необходимо вызвать `sqlite3_reset`.

Больше подробностей и прочие методы `sqlite3_bind_*` можно найти [здесь](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html)

```
sqlite3_stmt* pStmt = nullptr;
std::string sql("INSERT INTO Users(Login, Password) VALUES (?1, ?2);");
result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql.c_str(), -1, &pStmt, nullptr);
if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Prepare error\n");
    return -1;
}
result = sqlite3_bind_text(pStmt, 1/*?1*/, InpLogin.c_str(), -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Bind text error\n");
}
result = sqlite3_bind_text(pStmt, 2/*?2*/, InpPassword.c_str(), -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Bind text error\n");
}
result = sqlite3_step(pStmt);
if ( result != SQLITE_DONE ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Execution error\n");
}
sqlite3_reset( pStmt );
sqlite3_clear_bindings( pStmt );
```