# Как вытащить запись из БД и поместить ее в переменную? Sqlite3 c++

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, sqlite3, select

Подскажите как правильнее будет сделать, потому что я SQL только начал активно использовать и в написании запросов не очень силен.
Я понял как выводить всю таблицу или отдельные ее записи, но мне нужно как то вытаскивать запись и класть ее в переменную, чтобы уже работать непосредственно с этими данными.

Тут я писал запросы, которые возвращают записи или таблицу:

```
static int selectData(const char* s)
{
    sqlite3* DB;
    char* messageError;

    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Users;";

    int exit = sqlite3_open(s, &DB);
    exit = sqlite3_exec(DB, sql.c_str(), callback, NULL, &messageError);

    if (exit != SQLITE_OK) {
        cerr << "Error in selectData function." << endl;
        sqlite3_free(messageError);
    }
    else
        cout << "Records selected Successfully!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Таблицу и записи я выводил в консоль вот таким образом:

```
static int callback(void* NotUsed, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) 

    {
       cout << azColName[i] << ": " << argv[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А покажите, как вы выводите записи в консоль.

Comment: Как минимум, генерировать запрос и кусочков строк - [зло](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0), в sqlite был какой-то встроенный механизм подстановки параметров в запрос.

Comment: А я не хочу в консоль выводить записи), я хочу сравнить запись которая лежит в бд с переменной, которую вводит пользователь, вот что я хочу сделать.
Хотя стоп, а можно ли переменную, введенную пользователем просто сравнивать с записью в бд? Или это бред полнейший?

Comment: Это я понял. Я имею в виду, что нет большой разницы между выводом на экран и сохранением в переменную, поэтому если вы умеете делать одно, то второе должно быть просто. *"просто сравнивать с записью в бд"* Не понял.

Comment: добавил код в вопрос

Comment: казалось бы, что за такой тупой вопрос, возьми и выучи язык запросов сначала, пошарься в документации sqlite и сделай все, но так получилось, что мне на ходу надо в срочном порядке все сделать и времени досконально все выучить, а главное понять сейчас увы нет(
Так что, извиняюсь за достаточно тупой вопрос, но это вопрос и мне нужен на него ответ)

Comment: Дык вот в этой функции можно было бы взять и записать в перменную, вместо вывода на экран. Наверняка в sqlite есть более красивый способ это делать, но это тоже будет работать. *"надо в срочном порядке"* Вам сюда: http://www.reshaem.net/

Comment: а как именно в этой функции записать запись в переменную, я пробовал, но у меня ничего не получилось.

Answer (score 3):

### Через exec/callback

Если Вы хотите использовать callback функцию, то в её первый аргумент `void*` передаётся четвёртый аргумент функции `sqlite3_exec`.

Допустим, мы хотим получить пароль на основе логина. Мой запрос выглядит так:

```
SELECT `Password` FROM `Users` WHERE `Login` = 'test';
```

Тогда моя `callback` функция, которая должна записать мне значения пароля в `std::string`, будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
static int callback(void *pString, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
    if (argc>0) {
        std::string* str = static_cast<std::string*>(pString);
        str->assign(argv[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Здесь я исхожу из того, что знаю индекс искомого столбца (это `0`). В зависимости от ситуации можно обрабатывать элементы другим образом.

В коде это будет использоваться так:

```
std::string sql1("SELECT `Password` FROM `Users` WHERE `Login` = 'test';");
std::string outStr;
result = sqlite3_exec(db, sql1.c_str(), callback, &outStr, &err);
if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
    std::cerr << "Error in selectData function." << endl;
    sqlite3_free(err);
}
std::cout << "Result:" << outStr << std::endl;
```

Важно понимать, что функция `callback` будет вызываться для каждой строки результата, что необходимо учесть при работе с первым аргументом.

### Через подготовленные выражения

В большинстве случаев более выгодно использовать подготовленные выражения.

В запросе заменим искомую строку на выражение формата `?NNN`, на место которого мы будем подставлять переменную:

```
SELECT `Password` FROM `Users` WHERE `Login` = ?1;
```

Переменная `pStmt` будет хранить указатель на подготовленное выражение `sqlite3_stmt*`, которое создастся в функции `sqlite3_prepare_v2`.

Функция `sqlite3_bind_text` свяжет выражение `?1` с подаваемым ему на вход объектом (в данном случае `InpLogin.c_str()`). Смотрите [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1470101/529836) на Ваш вопрос или [документацию](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html).

Функция `sqlite3_step` будет возвращать `SQLITE_ROW`, в случае если возможно получить ещё одну строку из ответа. Т.к. строк может больше одной обрабатываем их в цикле.

Функции группы `sqlite3_column_*` позволяют получать значения колонки в строке результата на основе подготовленного выражения. В данном случае используем `sqlite3_column_text` (Она возвращает `const unsigned char*` поэтому используем `reinterpret_cast`).

Завершаем работу с подготовленным выражением используя `sqlite3_finalize`.

```
std::string InpLogin = "test";
sqlite3_stmt* pStmt = nullptr;
std::string sql2("SELECT `Password` FROM `Users` WHERE `Login` = ?1;");
result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql2.c_str(), -1, &pStmt, nullptr);
if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
     std::cerr  << "Prepare error\n";
    return -1;
}
result = sqlite3_bind_text(pStmt, 1 /*?1*/, InpLogin.c_str(), -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
    std::cerr  << "Bind text error\n";
}
while (true) {
    result = sqlite3_step(pStmt);
    if (result == SQLITE_ROW) {
        outStr.assign(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(pStmt, 0)));
        //Работаем со строкой
        std::cout << "Result:" << outStr << std::endl;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
if ( result != SQLITE_DONE ) {
    std::cerr  << "Execution error\n";
}
sqlite3_finalize(pStmt);
```

### Касательно запроса

Вероятно в Вашем случае следует использовать другой запрос, который сравнил бы значения переменных на стороне БД:

```
SELECT `Users` FROM `Users` WHERE `Login` = ?1 AND `Password` = ?2;
```

В случае если он ничего не вернёт, то искомого пользователя с такой парой Login/Password не существует. С аналогичной целью можно запросить количество пользователей с искомой парой Login/Password:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Users` WHERE `Login` = ?1 AND `Password` = ?2;
```

Comment: Во первых спасибо большое, что в принципе откликнулись на вопрос)
Получается правильным вариантом будет отправлять введенные данные (логин, пароль) в бд и там строго сравнивать их с записями полей и возвращать true или false?
Верно понял?)

Comment: @Axiles В основном верно, правда возвращаемые значения будут не true/false. Если есть какой-либо отбор по полям, то лучше всегда делать его на стороне БД. Отправка же правильного пароля обратно пользователю звучит небезопасно сама по себе, но это не так критично для sqlite т.к. это встраиваемая бд.

Comment: Согласен, не очень безопасный вариант я сначала выбрал, но будем честны я со sqlite третий день работаю только, да и с языком запросов тоже, а как будет выглядеть запрос, который будет сравнивать, введенные значения с записями тогда?

Comment: @Axiles Я в конце ответа привёл два примера. Первый, который возвращает поле, можно будет использовать, если в таблице будет ещё какая-нибудь полезная информация, а второй просто вернёт вам 0 в случае, когда записей удовлетворяющим критериям отбора нет. Вам возможно стоит почитать что-нибудь про `WHERE`, [например](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-where/).

Comment: Спасибо большое))
Очень приятно, что не послали меня куда подальше, а нормально все объяснили.
Спасибо еще раз.
Просто я студент безопасник)), но нас так "хорошо" учат, что я учусь в основном сам, и тема программирования в том же инфобезе меня увлекает больше, чем создание, установка оборудования и настройка сетей, поэтому я сейчас активно учу плюсы ну и бд тоже, а соответственно и язык запросов))